# All AsynTask of the app stop calling api

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am developing an application which has many network calls , so i need to call  api all the time when app is in foreground. This is working absolutely fine , but some time (random behaviour ) all the network calls stops and any event that has to call api stops working. Please advice me on this , i am looking for suggestions on how to handle multiple networks calls instead of code, or is there any other efficient way to manage the api calls.

Comment: We really need code. Also, Anything interesting in Logcat?

Comment: Yes there is an efficient way, use retrofit. Than there's no need fot asynctask.

Comment: I dont find anything interesting in logcot, infact it shows nothing. This is not simply with one asyntask i am talking about all the calls of app . The behaviour is like the phone just got hanged

Answer (score 3):

You need to check status of each `AsyncTask` to see that the task is running or not if running then cancel them. To check the status of `AsyncTask` do something like

```
if(asyncTask != null && (asyncTask..getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING)){
     asyncTask.cancel(true);
 asyncTask = null;
}
```

here asyncTask is object of `AsyncTask`.